Problem communicating with backend server with Stripe Payments on SwiftUI App
I have an app using Stripe Payments that uses a view called StripePaymentView that allows users to create a Stripe Payment on the app and it works great as long as StripePaymentView is called from the initial struct MySwiftUIApp: App file in the WindowGroup as shown below
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData
import Stripe

@main
struct MySwiftUIApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            StripePaymentView()
            //ContentView()
            /*
            ResponsiveView {properties in
                MainTabbedView(layoutProperties: properties)
                    .modelContainer(for: SavedFavBooksFromISBNDB.self)
            }
            
            .onOpenURL { incomingURL in
                let stripeHandled = StripeAPI.handleURLCallback(with: incomingURL)
                if (!stripeHandled) {
                    // This was not a Stripe url – handle the URL normally as you would
                }
            }*/
        }
    }
}

The code works as I can see the payment intent get created for the correct amount when looking at the debug console on the backend server running my express.js script see below
{paymentIntentID: 'pi_3PxEmnJ15oFjjfNB10B4Cm8o', amount: 7744}

However when I try to push the view "StripePaymentView" from any other subview in the app where it has to be placed I get an error when communicating to the backend server.
Here is the debug console error on backend server

Below is the code for StripePaymentView
import SwiftUI
import StripePaymentSheet

struct StripePaymentView: View {
    @FocusState var textFieldFocused: Bool
    @ObservedObject var model = StripePaymentHandler()
    
    @State private var enteredNumber = ""
    var enteredNumberFormatted: Double {
        return (Double(enteredNumber) ?? 0) / 100
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Enter the amount")
            ZStack(alignment: .center) {
                Text("$\(enteredNumberFormatted, specifier: "%.2f")").font(Font.system(size: 30))
                TextField("", text: $enteredNumber, onEditingChanged: { _ in
                    model.paymentAmount = Int(enteredNumberFormatted * 100)
                }, onCommit: {
                    textFieldFocused = false
                }).focused($textFieldFocused)
                    .keyboardType(.numberPad)
                    .foregroundColor(.clear)
                    .disableAutocorrection(true)
                    .accentColor(.clear)
            }
            Spacer()
            
            if let paymentSheet = model.paymentSheet, !textFieldFocused {
                PaymentSheet.PaymentButton(
                    paymentSheet: paymentSheet,
                    onCompletion: model.onPaymentCompletion
                ) {
                    payButton
                }
            }
        }
        .alert(model.alertText, isPresented: $model.showingAlert) {
            Button("OK", role: .cancel) { }
        }
        .onChange(of: textFieldFocused) {
            if !textFieldFocused {
                DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).sync {
                    model.updatePaymentSheet()
                }
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            model.preparePaymentSheet()
        }
        .padding(.horizontal)
        .padding(.top, 50)
        .padding(.bottom)
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .keyboard) {
                Button("Done") {
                    textFieldFocused = false
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    @ViewBuilder
    var payButton: some View {
        HStack {
            Spacer()
            Text("Pay $\(enteredNumberFormatted, specifier: "%.2f")")
            Spacer()
        }
        .padding()
        .foregroundColor(.white)
        .background(
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10, style: .continuous)
                .fill(.indigo)
        )
    }
}

And the code for StripePaymentHandler which communicates with backend
import StripePaymentSheet
import SwiftUI

class StripePaymentHandler: ObservableObject {
    @Published var paymentSheet: PaymentSheet?
    @Published var showingAlert: Bool = false
    
    private let backendtUrl = URL(string: "http://18.XXX.XX.XX:3000")!
    

    private var configuration = PaymentSheet.Configuration()
    private var clientSecret = ""
    private var paymentIntentID: String = ""
    
    var alertText: String = ""
    var paymentAmount: Int = 0
    
    func preparePaymentSheet() {
        // MARK: Fetch the PaymentIntent and Customer information from the backend
        let url = backendtUrl.appendingPathComponent("prepare-payment-sheet")
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { [weak self] (data, response, error) in
            guard let data = data,
                  let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String : Any],
                  let customerId = json["customer"] as? String,
                  let customerEphemeralKeySecret = json["ephemeralKey"] as? String,
                  let clientSecret = json["clientSecret"] as? String,
                  let paymentIntentID = json["paymentIntentID"] as? String,
                  let publishableKey = json["publishableKey"] as? String,
                  let self = self else {
                // Handle error
                return
            }
            
            self.clientSecret = clientSecret
            self.paymentIntentID = paymentIntentID
            STPAPIClient.shared.publishableKey = publishableKey
            
            // MARK: Create a PaymentSheet instance
            configuration.merchantDisplayName = "Example, Inc."
            configuration.customer = .init(id: customerId, ephemeralKeySecret: customerEphemeralKeySecret)
            configuration.allowsDelayedPaymentMethods = true
            configuration.applePay = .init(
              merchantId: "merchant.com.your_app_name",
              merchantCountryCode: "US"
            )
            configuration.returnURL = "your-app://stripe-redirect"
        })
        task.resume()
    }
    
    func updatePaymentSheet() {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
           self.paymentSheet = nil
        }
        
        let bodyProperties: [String: Any] = [
            "paymentIntentID": paymentIntentID,
            "amount": paymentAmount
        ]
        
        let url = backendtUrl.appendingPathComponent("update-payment-sheet")
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: bodyProperties)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { [weak self] (data, response, error) in
            guard let self = self else {
                // Handle error
                return
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
               self.paymentSheet = PaymentSheet(paymentIntentClientSecret: self.clientSecret, configuration: self.configuration)
            }
        })
        task.resume()
    }
    
    func onPaymentCompletion(result: PaymentSheetResult) {
        switch result {
        case .completed:
            self.alertText = "Payment complete!"
        case .canceled:
            self.alertText = "Payment canceled!"
        case .failed(let error):
            self.alertText = "Payment failed \(error.localizedDescription)"
        }
        
        showingAlert = true
    }
}

And here is the express.js script running on the backend server
const stripe = require('stripe')('sk_test_XXXX');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());

app.post('/prepare-payment-sheet', async (req, res) => {
    const customer = await stripe.customers.create();
    const ephemeralKey = await stripe.ephemeralKeys.create({customer: customer.id},
                                                           {apiVersion: '2024-04-10'});
    const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
        amount: 1099,
        currency: 'usd',
        customer: customer.id,
        automatic_payment_methods: {
            enabled: true,
        },
    });
    
    res.json({
        paymentIntentID: paymentIntent.id,
        clientSecret: paymentIntent.client_secret,
        ephemeralKey: ephemeralKey.secret,
        customer: customer.id,
        publishableKey: 'pk_test_XXXXX'
    });
});

app.post('/update-payment-sheet', async (req, res) => {
    const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.update(
        req.body.paymentIntentID,
        {
            amount: req.body.amount,
        }
    );
    console.log(req.body)
    console.log(res.body)
    
    res.json({});
});

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Running on port 3000'));


is your backendtUrl really http or is it a typo for https?

It’s http for now for testing and will switch later to https

So you have set the "NSAppTransportSecurity"
in your Info.plist to allow http connections.

@workingdog support Ukraine yes I had it added to info plist so it can communicate via http

From Stripe Support... Based on the error message "Unrecognized request URL (POST: /v1/payment_intents/)", it's most likely your code is making a PaymentIntent update request without specifying a PaymentIntent ID.   I'm not sure where to go with this as it specifies PaymentIntentID correctly per the log as long as StripePaymentView is pushed in opening view just not any other view

For anyone that this might help, I had to change @ObservedObject var model = StripePaymentHandler()
to @StateObject var model = StripePaymentHandler() in StripePaymentView, not sure why this worked it does!

You should never use ObservedObject where the object is owned. If you don’t use StateObject, a new one is created on every reevaluation of the view. That’s why this works.
